# Voltage sensitive dyes technique: What is the underlying measure?

Tags: neuroscience, terminology, neuroimaging, electrophysiology

I just discovered voltage [sensitive dyes technique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage-sensitive_dye):

I have seen that figures are labelled with dF/F0, what does it stands for?

Answer (score 5):

I found that dF/F0 stands for the relative difference in fluorescence at a certain wavelength.

[image: df]

Comment: normalized to average baseline fluorescence.  dF is change in fluorescence, and F0 is average baseline fluorescence.